# Jquery moving items from array using DIV tags

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate

Hi I am trying to call the images from the array to move using JQuery functions.

I have added a  tag to identify every div with the id Predator. I am calling them and move them when the "Play" button is click.

Unfortunately it dint. Can anyone help to spot the error?

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>  
        <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">

           //************** Array ***********************

            var Predatorlist = [];
            //uniqueid = "anchovies" + document.getElementById('amount').value;

            function addvalue()
            {
                Predatorlist.push(uniqueid)
                alert(Predatorlist);
            }

            function removevalue()
            {
                Predatorlist.pop(uniqueid)
                alert(x.innerHTML=Predatorlist);
            }

          //************** Array *********************** 

            var div = $("div");

            function runIt() {
                div.show("slow");
                div.animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
                div.slideToggle(1000);
                div.slideToggle("fast");
                div.animate({left:'-=200'},1500);
                div.hide("slow");
                div.show(1200);
                div.slideUp("normal", runIt);
            }

            function Add() {
                var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*101+1);
                x = Math.random() * 550;
                y = Math.random() * 250;
                if (document.getElementById('amount').value < 50){
                    document.getElementById('amount').value++;
                    svg = document.getElementById("main");

                    // construct uniqueid for the images
                    uniqueid = "<div id='Predator'>" + "frog" + document.getElementById('amount').value + "</div>";

                    //namespaces for SVG
                    svgNS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                    xlinkNS="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

                    // create a image element
                    image = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'image');

                    // set id and other attributes
                    image.setAttributeNS(null, "id", uniqueid);
                    image.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "href","jef-frog.gif");
                    image.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
                    image.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
                    image.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "50");
                    image.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "50");

                    // append to svg
                    svg.appendChild(image);

                } else {
                    alert("we got 50");
                }
            }

            function Remove() {

                if(document.getElementById('amount').value > 0)
                {         
                    document.getElementById('amount').value--;
                    svg = document.getElementById("main");
                    svg.removeChild(svg.lastChild);
                }
            }

            function numinput(e){
                // get the input value if enter
                key=e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (key==13){


                    total = document.getElementById("amount").value;
                    dummy = total;
                    // clear svg with image to avoid clearing the canvas
                    svg = document.getElementById("main");
                    element = svg.getElementsByTagName("image");
                    while(element.length>0){
                        element = svg.getElementsByTagName("image");
                        element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
                    }

                    // use the input to create the number of frog.
                    while (dummy>0)
                    {
                        Add();
                        dummy--;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("amount").value = total;
                }


            }

            /*function numeralsOnly(evt) {
             evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
             var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : 
             ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
             if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
             }
             return true;
             }
             */
            </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div>
            <SVG xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="main" style="border:inset 1px #000000;width:600;height:300"><param name='wmode' value='transparent'/></SVG>
        </div>
        <H2>TESTING</H2>
        PREY<BR/>
        <img src="jef-frog.gif" alt="frogsonice.com" width="100" height="100"/><BR/>

        <INPUT type="button" value="+" onClick="Add(); addvalue();"> 


            <!-- disabled the textfield -->
            <input type="text" id="amount" value=0  maxlength="3" size="1"  onkeypress="numinput(evt)">
                <INPUT type="button" value="-" onClick="Remove(); removevalue();">
                <INPUT type="button" value="Play" onClick="runIt();">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: There can be only one div with the id "Predator". JavaScript will only ever return the first one it finds. You need to use classes instead.

Comment: Blazemonger, because there is another part of my code is generating more elements with "Predator" tags.

Comment: Then you need to change that code. IDs are supposed to be unique, and there's not much you can do to make JavaScript look for more than one element with a given ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned "every div with the ID Predator". By definition, there can only be one element with the ID predator. You should look into using classes.

The easiest way to select all of the elements with the class is to use JQuery and simply use the below snippet. From there you can act on the elements with the class "Predator".

```
$('.Predator')
```

Comment: but I am using DIV ID ... not the classes for DIV